# SignalR give up when $.connection.hub.start() takes too long

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a scenario where I'm bumping into the well known browser connection limit (typically 6) with SignalR.

What I'd like to do is attempt to connect and after a certain period of time give up on the SignalR connection so I can use the rest of my web app.

For example:

1. I open 6 tabs, all connect to signalR fine.
2. I open that 7th tab and get the dreaded "Waiting for available socket..." message
3. After X seconds of waiting, it just gives up on connecting to SignalR and I continue using the rest of the web app without SignalR

It my perfect world it might look like this:

```
$.connection.hub.start().after30seconds(giveUp);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `TimeSpan` property in the signalr .NET client called `TransportConnectTimeout` that you can set before connecting.
I would search for that property in the javascript client though I´m not sure if it exists.